# My ivy leaves are turning hard with yellow to dark brown shade

Tags: diagnosis, leaves

[image]

My ivy leaves are turning a yellow shade then turning to a brown shade. The leaves also get a little more hard than usual.

Place is Kashmir, India

Answer (score 1):

Yellowing of leaves is often a sign of two factors

1. Water: Water issues — either too much or too little — are the leading reason behind yellow leaves. In overly wet soil, roots can't breathe. ... With too little water, plants can't take up essential nutrients. Yellow leaves result.
2. Mineral deficiency: often a sign of poor mineral uptake,